# how can i make make my project decide between these two

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my HTML response to different sizes I want the item{have shown it in the picture} change base on the screen size so I created two different script tag in HTML and tried to disable them base on the @media  that I used in CSS but it didn't work anyone has an idea to solve this problem?
I want this: whenever screen size is above 1000 the  first scripts become enabled and the second one becomes disabled and when the screen size is below 1000 second on becomes enable and the first one becomes disable

the HTML :

```
       <!-- enable when screen size above 1000  change to item:4 -->
    <script class="owl_options_above_1000">
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
              items:4,  //want to change this base on screen size
              loop:true,
              dots:true,
              autoplayspeed:1000,
              smartspeed:1500,
              autoplayhoverpause:true
            });
         });
       </script>
          <!-- enable when screen size below 1000 change to item:2 -->
       <script class="owl_options_below_1000">
          $(document).ready(function() {
             $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
                items:2,  //want to change this base on screen size
                loop:true,
                dots:true,
                autoplayspeed:1000,
                smartspeed:1500,
                autoplayhoverpause:true   
               });
            });
        </script>
```

the CSS :

```
@media screen and (max-width:1000px){
   .owl_options_above_1000{
       display: none;
    }
   .owl_options_below_1000{
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width:1001px){
   .owl_options_above_1000{
    }
   .owl_options_below_1000{
      display: none;
    }
}
```

here is the picture:
[HTML and css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fLHR.png)

Comment: Isn't there a "responive:" property on owl-carousel that could do exactly what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it doesn't 100% exactly answers your asked question. But for your specific case you can use the `responsive` propery of owlCarousel. It basically does what you are trying to achieve.

Otherwise you would have to listen to the `resize` Event on the window and then see if your specific breakpoint is reached and execute your code depending on that. If you also need an example for that let me know.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    dots:true,
    autoplayspeed:1000,
    smartspeed:1500,
    autoplayhoverpause:true
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items:2,
      },
      1000: {
        items:4
      }
   }
    });
}
```

If you really need to check for the screen width. You probably gotta do smth. like

```
const reactToScreenWidth = e => {
    if (this.innerWidth < 1000) {
    // Do smth. on small screen
  } else {
    // Otherwise do smth. on large screen
  }
};

// Check for screen width on page load
reactToScreenWidth();

// Check for screen width on resize
window.addEventListener('resize', reactToScreenWidth)
```

If you really want to do smth. like mentioned above. I would highly recommend you looking into `throttle` and `debounce` implementations so the event is not triggered to often upon resizing.

Comment: thank you it worked perfectly and you answered it the right way that I need it

Comment: it worked fine and solved my problem but I would like to know the other way if you don't have any problem with it mainly the execution of it how do you do it?

Comment: Added an example. Would be cool if you mark the answer as correct. So the thread can be closed and doesn't have to be looked on by other people trying to help! For other question feel free to open a new question.